# What is the kernel of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the kernel of the linear transformation: $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x-y,z)$?
Select one:

a. $\mathbb{R}^3$

b. $\mbox{Span}\{(1,1,0)\}$

c. $\mbox{Span}\{(1,-1,0)\}$

d. $\{(1,-1,0)\}$

Here's what I did:

I know that kernel means that $T(u)=0$, so $x-y=0$ and $z=0$. This simplifies to $x=y$ and $z=0$. So basically all values of the kernel would be multiples of ${(1,1,0)}$ and the answer would be b. Is this correct?

Comment: Yess, it is correct. You can see it like this: $$\textrm{Ker}(T)=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3: T(x, y, z)=0\}=\{(x, y, z): (x-y, z)=0\}=\{(x, y, z): x-y=0=z\}=\{(x, x, 0): x\in\mathbb R\}=\{x(1, 1, 0): x\in\mathbb R\}=\textrm{Span}\{(1, 1, 0)\}.$$

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. and perhaps the easiest way to see that is to realize $\;\dim\ker T=1\;$ since the homogeneous system $\;\begin{cases}x=y\\z=0\end{cases}\;$  has only one "freedom variable", say $\;x\;$ , meaning: once you know the value of $\;x\;$ you already know completely the solution. Thus, if $\;x=\pi\;$ then also $\;y=x=\pi\;$ , and of course $\;z=0\;$ , so the (particular) solution is $\;(\pi,\pi,0)=\pi(1,1,0)\;$ , and etc. This is in fact what determines (b) as the solution.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks a lot for helping!